# controller doesn't return view on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to setup code igniter. directory structure is

- application
- system
- public_html

since application and system are outside of public_html I setup variables inside `public_html/index.php`

```
$system_path = '../system';
```

and

`$application_folder = '../application';`

also inside application/config/routes default controller is set to my home controller

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
```

Now when I point to `www.mysite.com/index.php` controller returns view (from my default home controller) correctly as it should, but I cannot access to this view using `www.mysite.com/home`

Why is that ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to amend your htaccess file to strip out index.php in order to be able to access it at `www.mysite.com/home`. You also need to set the value of index_page to '' in the config file.

Take a look at the [CodeIgniter documentation on URLs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: does that mean that I should be able now to see using url like www.mysite.com/index.php/home, cause I dont.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to see it. I would take a look at your web server's error logs to see if something is up.